# PC Boots with two RAM sticks but won’t boot if another RAM stick is added

Tags: ramdisk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZXEg.jpg)My PC won’t start up after putting in more than two RAM sticks. All it does is light up the DRAMM light. And it won’t move on to boot. I have 4 RAM sticks of same type

- **Motherboard**: ASUS B550-Pro
- **RAM**: Kingston HyperX Fury 8GB 8x2 GB

Prosessor: amd ryzen 5 5600x 6-core

Has anyone had a similar problem?
Sorry for lack of detail. I havent built a pc my self before

Comment: If the new sticks are very different than it can happen.

Comment: They are all of the same type

Comment: Are you are max memory (BIOS)?   Did you put the sticks in 1, 2, 1, 2 kind of order?

Comment: @Drumbal Please provide info on what motherboard make and model this is happening on. Also, please edit your question to add more details/specifics about the RAM; the two RAM sticks that work and the third that seems to prevent boot. You say “They are all of the same type…” but what you describe is exactly what happens when there is a mismatch. Providing exact details can help us help you better diagnose this.

Comment: Motherboard is a asus b550-pro. And the ram bricks are kingston fury 8x2 gb. I have 4 of them total. When i put in b1 and b2 it boots just fine. But when i try to put in the 2 others in a1 and a2 it wont go past the ram light. I tried switching up wich ram bricks i was using in the b slots, and it would still boot fine.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add info.

Comment: We need to have (A) Photos of all RAM sticks (B) Processor model. Please edit all information into the question. If you can't take photos of RAM, report ALL written information on your RAM sticks. There are several models og "Kingston Fury 8x2 Gb". They could have different speeds, for example

Comment: I believe that the issue might be attempting to upgrade to a 3rd stick of RAM without a 4th stick of RAM. Seems like it might need to be upgraded in pairs?

Comment: I bought a upgrade kit for my pc. It came with 4 ram sticks. But it wont work with more than 2. the manual says the same as you described, and thats what i have done

Comment: It worked! Lowering the frequency made it able to run with all 4 sticks

Comment: @Drumbal Cool! I suggest you post the lowering of the frequency stuff as an answer and self-select it as the answer. This can help you help the community if someone else ever has an issue like this.